# What's wrong with this MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table.

```
id  name                    parents  
1   Apparel                                                                    
46  Apparel                 1                                                  
47  Child Apparel           1,46                                               
49  Child Apparel 2         46,1
```

I tried this query and it works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE 1 IN (parents)

id  name           parents
46  Apparel        1                                                  
47  Child Apparel  1,46
```

Why this query brings 1 record instead of 2?

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE 46 IN (parents)

id  name             parents
49  Child Apparel 2  46,1
```

Comment: seems to me first query has return 3 rows in result. what is it at all? something like many-to-many relation? both your queries work equally, they return rows where parents starts from specified number

Comment: The design violates First Normal Form and you should fix it if possible http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of IN:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE FIND_IN_SET('46', parents)
```

Note that this query will be slow. You should redesign your database. I suggest you look at this slideshow for better ways to store heirarchical data in MySQL:

- [Models for hierarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

Comment: You mean normalizing it to multiple tables is faster that this model?

Comment: @UmairAshraf: Yes, the normalized version can give better performance because it will be able to make better use of indexes.

Comment: So from the slides, presenter didn't mention which is efficient to use for hierarchical data instead he mentioned level of complexity for each. What do you suggest. I have used Closure Table before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain category table there is worng way you have maintain this table.

root category in parent only contain 1
sub  category in parent contain value of the root category

so parent column only maintain 1 value not more then 1 value with , as you mention

you can also fetch that record using recursive function

```
function showlist($parent) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM categorie WHERE parentID='$parent'");
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if($catlistids!=""){ $catlistids .= ", "; }
$catlistids .= $line["ID"];
showlist($line["ID"]);

}
return $catlistids;

}
```

Comment: I hate recursive stuff. I don't either understand what do you mean.

Comment: you can use [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)